# Comparing logistic regression coefficients across similar models

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

I have a bunch of control demographic variables (collectively termed D) and a dependent variable of interest (y). I also have quite a few independent variables of interest (x<sub>i</sub>).

**Goal: I want to check which x has the strongest relationship with y.**

If I were to run a total of n logistic regressions, n=total number of x, in the following manner:

y = ax<sub>i</sub> + bD

I would get a total of n coefficients for each of the x variables. Aside from the x variable, all of the other variables are the same across models.

**Question: Would it be possible for me to compare the magnitudes of the x coefficients across models?** That is, if the coefficient for x<sub>1</sub> in its model is larger than x<sub>2</sub>'s, could I say that the former has a stronger relationship with y than the latter, barring any confounding variables that are unaccounted for in the model?

If not, is there a better way to accomplish my goal stated above?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As a first step I would highly recommend to draw scatterplots and compare the covariances with each other. With the method you described above you only compute the *linear* relationship between $X_i$ and $Y$ in any case. If you use the right command, scatterplots will be colored and the 'more red' the plot is, the stronger the linear relationship (https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html, `# Scatterplot Matrices from the glus Package`). These graphs normalize by taking the maximal cov of the $X_i$ to $Y$ as the maximum. As a second step you could then compute MI...

Comment: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) which should also uncover nonlinear relationships. In my opinion, this step is not absolutely necessary because you will probably spot any clear nonlinear relationship in the scatterplots.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will definitely use the methods you described to try to to tease out any non-linear relationships between the data.

Just to clarify - is the method that I described still valid, with the main drawback being that it only takes into account linear relationships? This is assuming that all the x variables are binary categorical variables as well.

Comment: First of all: For doing a logistic regression you need to have numerical input variables. The only variable that is allowed to be boolean is the target variable. Then the question is not whether it is valid (everything that gives you an order of the features is somewhat 'valid') but 'how valid' and/or how exactly it may lead you to wrong conclusions. Lets assume that all the $x_i$ are numeric and the target variable $y$ is boolean and you do a logistic regression. Doing it on every single variable is somewhat like assuming that the variables are conditionally independent and I guess that

Comment: this method will screw you if there are some relations between the variables (i.e. two variables being very important in their own respective rights but together they are absolutely useless because, e.g. it might happen that $x_1 = -x_2$). This is only the advanced step: In the most simple case it could be true that the coeffs of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are very different because, e.g.  it could happen that the variables operate in a completely different range like $x_2 = 100000*x_1$. In the end you should at least normalize all $x_i$ to, say $[0,1]$ and then do a logistic regression with all of the

Comment: $x_i$ together, i.e. compute the model like its is supposed to be: $\sigma(z) = 1/(1+e^{-z})$ and then $\text{prediction}(x) = \sigma(a_1 x_1 + ... + a_d x_d)$. Then the coeffs of the conjoint model $a_i$ have essentially the same meaning for you as the single ones but the model has the chance to incpoperate some relations between all the $x_i$. However, in the case of a logistic regression model you are still in trouble if there are (even simple like linear) relationships between the $x_i$.

Comment: The full answer I guess is to take a complicated model (like gradient boosting) and then compute a model with *every* possible selection $x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, ..., x_{i_k}$ of the inputs. However, there are way to many combinations to finish with that process before the universe ends, hence, what I prefer to do is to compute it once with all variables and then spot the ones that the model thinks of with the highest importance by eye in order to see what is going on. In that way I play around and craft new features into the same direction as the most important old ones...